# Changing the domain name for a store in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm trying to change a domain name for one of for websites in a Magento multistore setup.

Each Store has it's own website, store, and view. We're replacing the old domain (domain1) with a new domain, and we're going to switch to a new domain (domain2).

I haven' been able to find information on changing a domain, except for the Magento article "Moving Magento to another server" http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

I've updated all of the base_url values in the core_config_data table in MySQL, but when I access the store using domain2, Magento still redirects to domain1.

Has anyone had any success in changing the domain name for a Magento store, or is there a way I can simply add an alias to the store? Again, this is a multistore setup, and domain1 is not my default store, so I cannot simply add a ServerAlias to my Apache configuration. Is this something I could do by adding a store view?

Comment: Make sure and wipe out your cache.  It may still have the old values keeping the article from working as you expect.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue especially if you changed the core config data table. Maybe check your index.php script? See if its dictating routing from there...

Comment: just to make sure: did you also update the values for the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` paths in `core_config_data`?

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen I did, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have such a problem when moving from the sub-dir into root. Turned out to be caching issue. If you are not able to get into administrator interface to clear your cache, just delete /var/cache directory.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I got a little impatient. Was a little too focused on DNS cacheing because I'd just redirected my domain. Didn't even consider Magento cacheing.